# What is the meaning of gim boy?

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language, names

I received an e-mail from Spotify Customer Support a few months ago. They ended the email with the following:

"*Looking forward to hearing from you. Let us know if you have other questions or concerns. We're just an email away.*

*Until then,*

*Gim Boy*

*Spotify Customer Support*"

I thought the name "Gim Boy" was rather peculiar, so I looked it up online. What I discovered was that, according to Urbandictionary.com, the word 'gim boy' means 'gay boy' and can be used as an insult.

To be certain, is Gim Boy a real name, and can it also be used as an insult?

Comment: Do you trust 'Urban Dictionary'?

Comment: Given (1) its place in the message, between a valediction ("until then") and a company name and department "Spotify Customer Support" and (2) the capitalisation, it is clear that Gim Boy is the name (or pseudonym) of the sender.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_(Korean_surname)), **Gim** is just another rendering of the common surname **Kim**:

> Kim or Gim is the most common surname in Korea.

**Boy**, again according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_(name)), is used as a given name, nickname  or surname:

> Boy is a masculine given name, nickname, and surname.

Since the *order* in which names are rendered depends on culture, it is very well possible that this person's surname is Gim, and his given name is Boy.